# Virtual machine access denied by MFA in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-bastion

how can I enable multi factor factor authentication in virtual machine in azure. it denied multi factor factor authentication how can I connect my virtual machine through bastion etc

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy and configure Azure Bastion from the Azure Portal itself. Ensure you fulfil the specified [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/tutorial-create-host-portal#prerequisites) before getting started.

In the Azure portal, you first have to create a Bastion host in your virtual network. It takes about 5 minutes for the Bastion resource to be created and deployed.

After deploying the resource, you connect to a VM via its private IP address using the Azure portal. Your VM does not need a public IP address or special software. Once the service is provisioned, the RDP/SSH experience is available to all of the virtual machines in the same virtual network. Refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/tutorial-create-host-portal) for a detailed walkthrough.